# which encryption method is it?

Tags: encryption, decryption

i have a file and i want to edit it to do some changes but i think the file is encrypted anybody knows the encryption method? thanks

> ELF > @æ@ @ F¾        @ 8  @ 0 /       @       @ @     @ @     0
> 0                   p      p@     p@
> @       @     ðwF    ðwF                  ÐyF    Ðy¦    Ðy¦    ¨¥
> àF à¦ à¦ ð ð Œ Œ@ Œ@ ¨ ¨ ÐyF Ðy¦ Ðy¦ Påtd ÚD Ú„ Ú„ T7 T7 Qåtd Råtd ÐyF
> Ðy¦ Ðy¦ 0& 0& /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 GNU S Go
> oCYfJBje3xWaPhOGi0iA/XR56hwq0e7I--oaUSyYe/AZCRgBTn1fXAvR13RYbA/cB2Me6jD30LOvCXuFLAo
> GNU (eÖ¿GÅ¹~;ö<ä1ú’¾• d @ &@ ˆ €J A‚@@ Ð‚ €”@€" ¿ BdCN„ D ¡ @D @ Dˆ€ Ä
> É 4D@ ± l, Ð 1€ ( Ò H@@4a@ …ˆ €Q L"€(@:  #@T \ $€!À€ E€"a !Q A Ë ÀÀ
> A„h H€N"€$€ „€0 GÄ B À@$ <Á R@"¢`] € $ ( @H Œ€ ­„ Â„ € B ‰@ € † A P@(
> @¨( %²@Gdd ’ˆ ’( @¢ ¨„ H‚€‚ , ˆ"   f…*€%H¨0 ( Pd‡ iˆ@0€H„‚ @ …è)Ä A
> À¤ €0ˆ@ h8 @h d e h i j k l m n o p q r u y ~ ‚ „ … Š ‹ ’ “ ” • — ™ š
> › œ ž   ¡ ¢ ¤ ¥ © ª ­ ® ° ² µ ¹ º » ¼ ½ ¿ Á Ã Å É Ê Í Ð Ò Ó × Ú Ü Þ â
> ã æ ç è ê ì í î ï ò ô ÷ ø û ý þ

Comment: What makes you even think this is encryption? This looks like a ELF binary to me, i.e. an executable Linux program.

Comment: so why there is no .elf extension on file and i can't open it with dolphin emu?

Comment: *"so why there is no .elf extension on file"* - that's not how things work. Linux binaries typically don't have any extension. But this is actually about a general understanding how things work and not about information security, i.e. off-topic.